# Null Pointer Exception While trying to Connect to FTP server

Tags: java, android, ftp

```java
FTPClient mFTPClient;

mFTPClient = new FTPClient();

// connecting to the host

mFTPClient.connect(host, port);
```

After this line of code, the following exception thrown.

> Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate android.system.StructAddrinfo.toString()

Comment: Jens will you please share the URL of already existed question?

Comment: see it at the top of your question.